# How to bind ListView inside ListView in WinRT Metro application

Tags: listview, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have two ListViews in my application . 
Here is my Model class

```
  public class SurveyDetailViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _RoomTypeId;
    private string _RoomType;

    public int RoomTypeId
    {
        get { return _RoomTypeId; }

        set
        {
            _RoomTypeId = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("RoomTypeId");
        }
    }

    public string RoomType
    {
        get { return _RoomType; }

        set
        {
            _RoomType = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("RoomType");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<SurveyProductDetails> SurveyProductDetails { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    } 
}


 public class SurveyProductDetails : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Guid _RoomId;
    private int _ProductTypeId;
    private string _Title;
    private string _Color;
    private int _Quantity;
    private int _QuantityInstalled;
    private string _RoomDescription;
    private string _ProductDescription;
    private string _ProductSpecification;
    public Guid RoomId
    {
        get { return _RoomId; }

        set
        {
            _RoomId = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("RoomId");
        }
    }
    public int ProductTypeId
    {
        get { return _ProductTypeId; }
        set
        {
            _ProductTypeId = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ProductTypeId");
        }
    }
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _Title; }
        set
        {
            _Title = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Title");
        }
    }
    public string Color
    {
        get { return _Color; }
        set
        {
            _Color = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Color");
        }
    }
    public string ProductSpecification
    {
        get { return _ProductSpecification; }

        set
        {
            _ProductSpecification = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ProductSpecification");
        }
    }
    public string ProductDescription
    {
        get { return _ProductDescription; }

        set
        {
            _ProductDescription = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ProductDescription");
        }
    }
    public int Quantity
    {
        get { return _Quantity; }

        set
        {
            _Quantity = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Quantity");
        }
    }
    public int QuantityInstalled
    {
        get { return _QuantityInstalled; }

        set
        {
            _QuantityInstalled = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("QuantityInstalled");
        }
    }
    public string RoomDescription
    {
        get { return _RoomDescription; }

        set
        {
            _RoomDescription = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("RoomDescription");
        }
    }
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    } 
}
```

I have an Observable Collection object

```
 ObservableCollection<SurveyDetailViewModel> surveyDetail = new ObservableCollection<SurveyDetailViewModel>();
```

which gets the data . I tried to set the ItemSource of Outer ListView to surveyDetail

```
ItemsSource="{Binding surveyDetail}"
```

and Inner one like this

```
ItemsSource="{Binding surveyDetail.SurveyProductDetails}"
```

I also tried this to inner one

```
ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=SurveyProductDetails}"

ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=surveyDetail.SurveyProductDetails}"
```

Outer ListView is working fine but inner ListView not binding at all . Need help what I am doing wrong .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a ListBox bound to an ObservableCollection each item in that list is given a datacontext which is the corresponding object in the collection. In this case each top level ListBoxItem is bound to an object of type SurveyDetailViewModel.

Therefore, your ItemsSource just needs to be:

`{Binding SurveyProductDetails}`

surveyDetail can be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the page is bound to the viewmodel you can use this binding

```
ItemsSource="{Binding SurveyProductDetails}"
```

I would make SurveyProductDetails a readonly only property that you make sure the backing field is not null when the get is called.